# copy and paste a cell from one worksheet to another and multiply it by a value

Tags: vba, excel

```
Worksheets(stockcode & "_CF_" & marketcode).Range("B11").Copy
Worksheets(stockcode & "_Stock ratio_" & marketcode).Range("D16").PasteSpecial
```

I am running this two lines of code to copy from one worksheet and pasting it onto another worksheet. In the midst of it, I want to multiply it by -1 before pasting onto the last worksheet. Any ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you just want to copy one cell and it (hopefully) is a number you just could write:

```
Worksheets(stockcode & "_Stock ratio_" & marketcode).Range("D16") = Worksheets(stockcode & "_CF_" & marketcode).Range("B11")* -1
```